# Mixed-model Harrell-Davis estimator for reference range

Tags: mixed-model, clinical-trials

We have measured a physiological parameter describing a gastric mechanism in 26 healthy volunteers. To establish a reference range of the parameter, we use the Harrell-Davis estimator, `hdquantile` in R.

For 13 subjects, we have measured the parameter twice on separate occasions; carry-over effects can be ruled out with certainty, but there is a relevant within-subject correlation (about r = 0.7).

If the endpoint were some between-treatment comparison, a mixed-model would be adequate. But how do we take into account correlation when reference ranges are to be estimated?

Can someone point me to a paper or other reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Harrell-Davis estimator was developed only for the case where there are no repeated measurements.  It may actually work with pooled multiple record per case data but the standard error it gives will be way off (it might possibly be corrected using the cluster bootstrap).  But I would seek a more general approach.

The minimum sample size needed to estimate a reference range reliably, using any method, is probably in the hundreds.  And reference ranges are usually inconsistent with clinical decision making because they ignore the distribution of non-normal subjects.